# Closed linear Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

In Knapp's book 'Lie groups beyond introduction', he defined a closed linear group to be a closed subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb C)=\{\text{all}\ n\times n\ \text{nonsingular complex matrices}\}.$ My question is if this definition can be made independent of the ambient complex linear group. Technically we can not have that $G$ is a subset of both $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ and $GL(m,\mathbb C)$ where $m\neq n.$

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after.  But you can easily show it is equivalent to (up to isomorphism of Lie groups) $G$ being a Lie group with a finite-dimensional faithful representation over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the precise statement. Most likely, he means

"A topological group $G$ is said to be *closed linear* if it admits an embedding in $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$ for some $n$."

In this situation, an "embedding" is equivalent to "a continuous monomorphism with closed image." (An embedding is required to be a homomorphism which is a homeomorphism to its image.)

Thus, $n$ depends on $G$ and is not fixed in advance.

Aside: There are groups which are (complex) linear as abstract groups but do not admit embeddings  with closed image in any $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$.